# Angular - How to manage multiples multiple ng-content

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue. I have a component in which I declare an input

`@Input() isOverlay: boolean`

and I have a template html like this:

```
  <ng-template *ngIf="isOverlay" cdkConnectedOverlay [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger" [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="active">
    <div class="context-menu__header">
      <strong>{{ label }}</strong>
    </div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div class="context-menu__footer"></div>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngIf="!isOverlay">
    <div class="context-menu__header">
      <strong>{{ label }}</strong>
    </div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div class="context-menu__footer"></div>
  </ng-container>
```

It works but the double ng-content seems to be the issue. If I pass the boolean as true and I comment the second ng-content it works, if I remain all the two ng-content tags it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your issue (which isn't easy as you didn't provide much details).
This is what I've come up with: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4xwms7?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

*component.ts*

```
export class HelloComponent {
  isOpen = false;
}
```

*component.html*

```html
<button (click)="isOpen = !isOpen" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin">
   show overlay with stuff
</button>
<hr/>
<ng-template
*ngIf="isOpen"
cdkConnectedOverlay
[cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
[cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen"
>
   from overlay: 
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tpl"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
<div *ngIf="!isOpen">
   outside overlay: 
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tpl"></ng-container>
</div>
<ng-template #tpl>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
   World!
</ng-template>
```

You can have just one projection of `ng-content` in a single component. Thanks to having it inside, `ng-template` I can share it between multiple places. You still mustn't show it in many places at once, though.

If you want to display it in multiple times, you must nest it inside a separate template in the parent component and pass that `ng-template` using normal `@Input` binding. You can refer to this bit of documentation regarding this: https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#conditional-content-projection

Comment: I've updated the example to use Angular 17 with standalone component.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6tbor5?file=src%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Findex.html